# Ordering a query set based on the length of another query set

Tags: python, mysql, django, performance, python-3.x

I have these models:

```
class Team(models.Model):
    # stuff

class Alliance(models.Model):
    teams = models.ManyToManyField(Team)

class Match(models.Model):
    alliances = models.ManyToManyField(Alliance)
    winner = models.ForeignKey(Alliance, null=True, related_name='winner')
```

I am trying to order a list by `Team`s that have the most wins. I currently have this algorithm, which works, but is very slow:

```
from collections import Counter
def most_match_wins(n=None):
    matches = Match.objects.filter(winner__isnull=False)
    count = Counter()
    for m in matches:
        for team in m.winner.teams.all():
            count[team] += 1

    return count.most_common() if n is None else count.most_common(n)
```

I am trying to improve it now with aggregation/annotations that Django provides. However, I have reached a roadblock. I can retrieve the number of wins a `Team` has by executing this query:

```
Match.objects.filter(winner__in=my_team_object.alliance_set.all()).count()
```

Now I am not sure where to go from here. `django.db.models.Count` does not seem to offer the functionality that I am looking for, and the same for `django.db.models.F` / `django.db.models.Q`.

Any help would be appreciated. Maybe I am just not thinking about `F`/`Q` objects correctly.

Comment: Which list are you trying to order? Team, Alliance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you are trying to sort the teams based on their number of wins. In this case, you could annotate each `Team` object with the number of wins their related alliances have and then sort on those number of wins in decreasing order:

```
from django.db.models import Count
teams = Team.objects.annotate(num_wins=Count('alliance__winner')).order_by('-num_wins')
```

Comment: Holy cow, I think that did it. That's a great example that I can go off of in the future too. Thank you so much